# How to define list with index

Tags: coq

I have set with n elements with index.

```
Set S = {S0, S1, …, Sn-1}
```

I have to perform different mathematical operation on this set. Please guide me on how I should define this set in coq? ((Index,list)  [list( natlist)].

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with your data. What do you want with it?

Comment: I have used the below mention function to find the value in the list against the index.
Now want to assign different natural numbers to the list against the index.
If I make use of map(dictionary) function It will update one value against one key, but I want to update the whole list. @Winterhalter

Comment: Index function(to find element at different position) ,insert function(insert value against key in dictionary )